# SVG: Text not displayed on linked TextPath

Tags: svg

I am generating with JS and D3 an SVG.
The code below is a representative excerpt from the generated SVG.
In http://jsfiddle.net/c8qwjb4n/ the text is not drawn on the path but in the middle of the page, though it refers to group-11.
I am an absolute svg beginner, so probably it's just a matter of seconds for an expert...
Thanks in advance

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="svg" width="960" height="750">
<g transform="translate(480,375)">       
    <g class="group">
        <path d="M-146.8148124720131,-340.98676416953145A371.25000000000006,371.25000000000006 0 0,1 -18.55476659174032,-370.78603417163123L-16.867969628854837,-337.07821288330103A337.5,337.5 0 0,0 -133.46801133819372,-309.98796742684675Z"
            style="fill: rgb(170, 170, 170); stroke: rgb(170, 170, 170);"
            id="group-11" />
        <text>
            <textPath href="#group-11">Some text that should be connected to group-11</textPath>
        </text>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Oh damned...I used firebug to access the dynamically rendered SVG and he obviously returned href instead xlink:href due to the missing xmlns attributes. Thanks, now I am one step further

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "xlink:href" attribute to textPath element and add xmlns for svg and xlink at root svg element.

http://jsfiddle.net/defghi1977/51nsadLd/1/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="svg" width="960" height="750">
    <g transform="translate(480,375)">       
        <g class="group">
            <path d="M-146.8148124720131,-340.98676416953145A371.25000000000006,371.25000000000006 0 0,1 -18.55476659174032,-370.78603417163123L-16.867969628854837,-337.07821288330103A337.5,337.5 0 0,0 -133.46801133819372,-309.98796742684675Z"
                style="fill: rgb(170, 170, 170); stroke: rgb(170, 170, 170);"
                id="group-11" />
            <text>
                <textPath xlink:href="#group-11">Some text that should be connected to group-11</textPath>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: xlink:href is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href and this solution does not work in iOS.